# aligning text inside ag-grid cell vertically

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid

I am creating a grid that will be on a large screen and will need to have large row heights and text in order to be seen from a distance. The problem is the text in my cells are aligned to the top of the cell not centered. I have set my  rowHeight to 100 and rowClass to 'large-row'. I found the lower 3 lines of css online but it did no help. The image below shows my issue.

```
.large-row {
 text-align: center !important;
 font-size:2.5em;
 font-weight: bolder;

 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: normal;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Angular version 6.0.2

Comment: ..ag-cell {  justify-content: center;
}

Comment: @NagaSaiA that did not seem to work. I even added !important

Comment: @JamesMorris, try .ag-cell {
    line-height: 18px;
}

Comment: Change line height based on your row height to achieve vertically center

Comment: @NagaSaiA keep my row height at 100 in my gridOptions and set my  line-height in css also?

Comment: yes @JamesMorris, set line height in css for centering content vertically

Comment: Thanks @NagaSaiA that worked. I needed to refresh my grid.

Comment: @JamesMorris, posted my comment as answer , if it helped you , mark it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve expected result, set line-height in css for centering content vertically

```
.ag-cell { line-height: 18px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2+ has [an API called "fxFlex"](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API) which provides an HTML attribute called "fxLayoutAlign" that makes aligning elements a breeze.

First off, remove the bottom 3 CSS properties as well as the text-align property, as the fxLayoutAlign attribute will provide it for you:

```
.large-row {
   font-size:2.5em;
   font-weight: bolder;
}
```

In your HTML you will use a variation of the following:

```
<div class="large-row" fxLayoutAlign="center center"> ..... </div>
```

[This site](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs) allows you to play with the fxFlex API. I use it almost every day at my job. It's a wonderful resource